# A Magic Square (or is it?)

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

Sorry for taking so long but I've come up with a puzzle that I'm not sure is solvable but maybe you can help me with it?

Okay, at least a hundred of us know the traditional magic square right? You just arrange numbers in a square grid so that each cell contains one number and each row, column and diagonal of the grid has numbers that add up to the same total.

[image: Just a normal 5x5 magic square...]

But what we take a 5x5 grid and remove the middle cell?

[image: No middle cell this time...]

Now here's the question,

**Is it possible to arrange all the numbers 1 to 24 (no decimals of course) so that:**

**1) Each cell has only one number inside it**

**2) Every straight line of 5 cells has numbers that add up to the same total**

**If it's possible, how is it done? And if no such grid exists, why?**

(If you're ever feeling confused about rule 2, just refer to the image below this sentence.)

[image: I couldn't think of a description for this one. Sorry.]

Answer (score 4):

Such a square is fairly easy to construct:

> Start with any 5x5 magic square (actually only the rows/columns need to be equal, the diagonals can be ignored).
>  Permute the rows so that the cell containing 25 is in the middle row.
>  Permute the columns so that the cell containing 25 is in the middle column.
>  Remove the centre cell which now contains 25.
>
>  If we use the given magic square, we only need to swap row 3 and row 5 to put the 25 in the centre, resulting in this square:
>
> ```
>  17 24  1  8 15
>  23  5  7 14 16
>  11 18 xx  2  9
>  10 12 19 21  3
>   4  6 13 20 22
> ```